# Pinterest-iOS 2.3 and Swift: calling createPinWithImageURL results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, pinterest

Using the Pinterest-IOS SDK (2.3) I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when creating an instance of the SDK via the Swift Bridge and then calling createPinWithImageURL.  When converting the same code back to objective-c and then calling a wrapper method from Swift it works as expected.  The root cause seems to be passing the appID and suffix strings from Swift to Objective-C.

This code fails:

```
self.pinterest = Pinterest(clientId:"your_app_id", urlSchemeSuffix:"prod")!
if(pinterest.canPinWithSDK()) {
    pinterest.createPinWithImageURL(NSURL(string: imageUrl)!, sourceURL:NSURL(string: sourceUrl)!, description:pinDescription)
}
```

This succeeds when setting appId on the objective-c side:

```
    self.bainterest = PinterestWrapper.sharedInstance()
    baPinterest.pinRecipe(imageUrl, sourceURL:sourceUrl, description:pinDescription)
```

I've created a project that demonstrates this:

[Sample Project](https://github.com/shooley/pinterest-swift-issue)

Comment: your code is worked for me!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
        var pinterest:Pinterest = Pinterest()
        pinterest.setValue("your_app_id", forKey: "clientId")
        if(pinterest.canPinWithSDK()){
            pinterest.createPinWithImageURL(imageUrl, sourceURL:sourceUrl, description:pinDescription)
        }
```

funziona correttamente

Comment: @raffaele hello 
excuse me from where i can get my app id ? 
in the documentation : 
https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/
there is no need for it.
thanks :)

Comment: what's the different between: clientId and App_id ?!